# Is it possible to reset reference to another value in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, placement-new

I know generally it's impossible to reset a reference after it's already initialized.

However, I somehow try out the following code and it happens to work on both clang++ and g++.

My question is, is the following a valid (behavior-defined) C++?

```
std::string x = "x";
std::string y = "y";
std::string i = "i";
std::string j = "j";

// now references to x, y
std::pair<std::string &, std::string &> p { x, y };
p.first = "1"; //changes x
p.second = "2"; //changes y
// now references to i, j
new (&p) std::pair<std::string &, std::string &> {i, j};
p.first = "1"; //changes i
p.second = "2"; //changes j
```

The above code works on g++ and clang++, but is it good C++? Thanks.

Comment: You're not really rebinding the reference since you are encapsulating them in a value type of `std::pair` which acts as a sort of a reference wrapper now.

Comment: `new (&p) std::pair<std::string &, std::string &> {i, j};` doesn't change the reference, it executes the constructor of std::pair at the location of p. The address referenced doesn't change. It is exactly like doing `p[0] = i; p[1] = j;` or `p.key = i; p.value = j;` (i don't remind std::pair exactly)

Comment: Not sure you are still allowed to use `p` after placement new.

Comment: And in fact, you do not use references here.

Comment: BTW, you could just use assignment (`p = std::pair<std::string &, std::string &> {i, j};`) instead of placement `new`.  It looks better and is probably safer.

Comment: @HenriMenke: it doesn't rebind [Demo](https://ideone.com/sbTE2m), just modify `x`, `y`.

Comment: @Jarod42 that's what `std::launder` is for.

Comment: @HenriMenke wouldnlt assignment go *through* the reference rather than rebind it?  That's how `tie` works.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The snippet has undefined behaviour, but barely so. Conceptually, you destroyed the old references and created new ones, you didn't rebind the reference even if you reused the memory. This part is completely fine.

[The catch](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.life#7.3) is if the reused class contains `const` or reference members, then the original name of the variable cannot be used to refer to the new object

```
new (&p) std::pair<std::string &, std::string &> {i, j};
// p does not refer to the newly constructed object
p.first = "1";  // UB
p.second = "2"; // UB
```

The fix is simple, in this case

```
auto p2 = new (&p) std::pair<std::string&, std::string&> {i, j};
p2->first = "1";
p2->second = "2";
```

Another solution is the C++17 function [`std::launder`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder)

```
new (&p) std::pair<std::string &, std::string &> {i, j};
std::launder(&p)->first = "1";
std::launder(&p)->second = "2";
```

These rules [presumably](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/ptr.launder) enables the compiler to make more optimizations around references and const members.

Comment: Had to do a double take at the `std::launder` standard link. Was thrown off by the `[[nodiscard]]` attribute. Your last snippet is perfectly valid C++17(and 20), but it took me a moment to parse.

Comment: @StoryTeller I don't get why. Why is it strange for `std::launder`to be `[[nodiscard]]`? Is there a subtlety I missed?

Comment: @YSC - At a glance it looked to me like the last snippet discards the result (it doesn't though, it's obviously used). So I had a slight WTF moment. Then I recalled how on-point Passer By usually is, and I re-parsed the snippet

Comment: Thanks. I have read through all the documents and papers regarding launder, and found that the current implementation status in gcc and clang is that they do not optimize reference yet. That's why my code can still work right now but may not in the future. Adding launder is a must as long as the compiler supports C++17. Another interesting article says that in Google open source code base, 40% of placement new do not use a new pointer (they just rely on the object name even after placement new), but of course normally there will not be const or reference members.

Answer (score 20):

> My question is, is the following a valid (behavior-defined) C++?

[It could be](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.life#4). The key here is that pair. You ended the lifetime of the pair object, and started the lifetime of another pair object in the same storage (the placement new does both of these things).

But you should be aware you aren't rebinding any references. You kill an object that held references, and create a new on in the same spot. Conceptually, you had two "old" references, and now two "new" ones.

Your code could be fine because the pair is a simple structure that holds a pair of references, and it would be valid if the pair held any trivially destructible types. If however the d'tor of any pair element is not trivial, you'll have undefined behavior. Because destructors will not be executed as part of placement new.

The problem as [Passer By noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50039777/is-it-possible-to-reset-reference-to-another-value-in-c#comment87096470_50039877), is that you can't use `p` to refer to the "new object", because it holds references. That would be the cause of UB.

> is it good C++?

That's debatable. It certainly is not something one would expect to see often.

Comment: @StoryTeller Just double-checked the facts, sorry for the instant deleted comment. In that case, it would [just be UB](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/basic.life#7.3)

Comment: @PasserBy - Well, damn. Post it as an answer, and ping me so I can upvote.

Comment: Wouldn’t another way to ensure the destructor gets called, whether trivial or non-trivial, be to call it explicitly before placement `new`?

Comment: @Davislor - Yes, and the linked paragraph says as much IIRC. I just wanted to focus mostly on the code in OP.

Comment: To reset p in the compiler’s mind and avoid UB, see `std::launder`.

Comment: @JDługosz - You can't really reset `p` itself, since it's the name of a variable. It will always refer to the "old" object. But Passer By details how launder can be used in C++17.